# React: Calling function in Parent Component from Child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have 2 js files as below

**mainpage.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Filter from '../components/filterPane.js';

export default function MainPage() {
    const handleSubmit = () => {
        alert('inside submit');
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <br/>
            <div className='rowC'>
                <Filter handleSubmit={handleSubmit}/>
            </div>
        </div>
      );
}
```

and **filterPane.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

export default function ComplexGrid( {handleSubmit}) {

  const submitFilter = () => {
    handleSubmit(); // Call the parent function
  };

  return (
       <Button variant="contained" onClick={()=>{submitFilter()}}>Submit</Button>
  );
}
```

I want to call the **handleSubmit()** function in mainPage.js from the onclick() event in **filterPane.js**.

When I trigger the click event it gives me an error in console as **Uncaught TypeError: handleSubmit is not a function**.

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks,

Comment: What is it doing currently when you click the button?

Comment: It gives me an error "Uncaught TypeError: handleSubmit is not a function"

Comment: Based on this code it looks like it should work. If you `console.log(handleSubmit)` inside of `submitFilter` what do you see?

Comment: console.log(handleSubmit) shows "undefined" in console

Comment: Do you import from `filterPane.js` anywhere else in your code?

Comment: not in this 2 files

Comment: As in your entire codebase doesn't have any other imports of that file? Just wondering if you're importing it somewhere else and then using the component in a way where you are not passing it a `handleSubmit` prop.

Comment: No it is not being called any where else

Comment: Is this your actual code? Because I [can't reproduce it](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/so-function-test-tv77lr). Is it possible to try and create a [mre]? I personally can't see how the solution below would've been the fix to your issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the corrected code, along with explanations for the changes:

**mainpage.js:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Filter from '../components/filterPane.js'; // Correct import path

export default function MainPage() {
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    alert('inside submit');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <br />
      <div className='rowC'>
        <Filter handleSubmit={handleSubmit} /> // Pass handleSubmit as a prop
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**filterPane.js:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

export default function Filter(props) { // Receive props correctly
  const submitFilter = () => {
    props.handleSubmit(); // Access handleSubmit from props
  };

  return (
    <Button variant="contained" onClick={submitFilter}>Submit</Button> // Pass submitFilter directly
  );
}
```

> **Explanation of changes:**

- Import path: The import path in mainpage.js was incorrect. It's
  corrected to ../components/filterPane.js to match the file structure.
- Prop drilling: The handleSubmit function is passed as a prop from
  MainPage to Filter. This allows Filter to access and call the parent
  function.
- Prop access: In filterPane.js, the props object is correctly used to
  access the handleSubmit function.
- Event handling: The onClick handler in Filter directly calls
  submitFilter. There's no need to wrap it in another anonymous
  function.
- Function name: The component name in filterPane.js is changed from
  ComplexGrid to Filter to match the export name and usage in
  mainpage.js.
- With these corrections, the code should compile and run without the
  "handleSubmit is not a function" error, allowing you to call
  handleSubmit from the onClick event in filterPane.js.

Comment: Can i pass other parameters as well along with "props" like "<Filter FilterPaneList={filtersList} handleSubmit={handleSubmit}/>" and get it in the filterPane.js as "export default function Filter({FilterPaneList}, props) "  ??

Comment: Yes, you can pass multiple props to a component in React, including both named and unnamed props. Here's how you can do it in your case:

mainpage.js:

    <Filter FilterPaneList={filtersList} handleSubmit={handleSubmit} /> // Pass multiple props



filterPane.js:


export default function Filter({ FilterPaneList, handleSubmit, ...otherProps }) {
  // Access FilterPaneList and handleSubmit directly
  // Access other props using otherProps

  // ... rest of your component code
}

Comment: @Md.MojnuMiah While these are all valid changes I can't seem to see how this would fix OP's issue of "Uncaught TypeError: handleSubmit is not a function.". OP's code _as is_ [seems to work fine](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/so-function-test-tv77lr).

Comment: @SM079, I'm glad my solution worked for you! Happy coding!

Comment: @NickParsons, I agree with your assessment— I see that the OP's code does work. I simply offered him alternative solutions, which worked for him.

Answer (score 0):

In mainpage.js you import Filter from '../components/filterPane.js';

In filterPane.js you export the React component as "ComplexGrid" instead of "Filter". Change the exported name to Filter.

```
export default function Filter({handleSubmit}) {
```

(in mainpage.js you also use a  but this is missing an import)

Comment: It's a default export so the component can be called whatever in the module it's being imported in.